# Loading UTF-8 file in Python 3 using numpy.genfromtxt

Tags: python, csv, numpy, utf-8

I have a CSV file that I downloaded from WHO site (http://apps.who.int/gho/data/view.main.52160 , Downloads, "multipurpose table in CSV format"). I try to load the file into a numpy array. Here's my code:

```
import numpy
#U75 - unicode string of max. length 75
world_alcohol = numpy.genfromtxt("xmart.csv", dtype="U75", skip_header=2, delimiter=",")
print(world_alcohol)
```

And I get

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position
>   2: ordinal not in range(128).

I guess that numpy has a problem reading the string "Côte d'Ivoire". The file is properly encoded UTF-8 (according to my text editor). I am using Python 3.4.3 and numpy 1.9.2.

What am I doing wrong? How can I read the file into numpy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note the original 2015 date.  Since then `genfromtxt` has gotten an `encoding` parameter.

---

In Python3 I can do:

```
In [224]: txt = "Côte d'Ivoire"
In [225]: x = np.zeros((2,),dtype='U20')
In [226]: x[0] = txt
In [227]: x
Out[227]: 
array(["Côte d'Ivoire", ''],   dtype='<U20')
```

Which means I probably could open a 'UTF-8' file (regular, not byte mode), and readlines, and assign them to elements of an array like `x`.

But `genfromtxt` insists on operating with byte strings (ascii) which can't handle the larger `UTF-8` set (7 bytes v 8).  So I need to apply `decode` at some point to get an `U` array.

I can load it into a 'S' array with `genfromtxt`:

```
In [258]: txt="Côte d'Ivoire"
In [259]: a=np.genfromtxt([txt.encode()],delimiter=',',dtype='S20')
In [260]: a
Out[260]: 
array(b"C\xc3\xb4te d'Ivoire",  dtype='|S20')
```

and apply `decode` to individual elements:

```
In [261]: print(a.item().decode())
Côte d'Ivoire

In [325]: print _
Côte d'Ivoire
```

Or use `np.char.decode` to apply it to each element of an array:

```
In [263]: np.char.decode(a)
Out[263]: 
array("Côte d'Ivoire", dtype='<U13')
In [264]: print(_)
Côte d'Ivoire
```

`genfromtxt` lets me specify `converters`:

```
In [297]: np.genfromtxt([txt.encode()],delimiter=',',dtype='U20',
    converters={0:lambda x: x.decode()})
Out[297]: 
array("Côte d'Ivoire", dtype='<U20')
```

If the `csv` has a mix of strings and numbers, this `converters` approach will be easier to use than the `np.char.decode`.  Just specify the converter for each string column.

(See my earlier edits for Python2 tries).

Comment: Not OP but thanks for the clear and useful buildup of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works!
I am just beginning with Python and I find it weird that numpy can't read UTF-8 out-of-the-box. I have read that Python is easy and developed with simplicity and ease of use in mind yet reading UTF-8 requires additional convertion? I thought we are living in 2015.