# Python 3 shows UnicodeDecodeError when trying to print dataset with numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dataset

I am just getting started with numpy. So, just to play around I downloaded [FIFA 18 Complete Player Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/thec03u5/fifa-18-demo-player-dataset/data). Then, I tried to run a simple code :

> **import numpy as np
>
>   np_fifa = np.genfromtxt('Datasets/FIFA2018.csv', delimiter=',')
>
>   print(np_fifa)**

But it immediately shows this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\MyFiles\Programs\Python\PlayGround.py", line 2, in 
>       np_fifa = np.genfromtxt('Datasets/FIFA2018.csv', delimiter=',')
>     File "C:\Users\Vaibhav Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1951, in genfromtxt
>       for (i, line) in enumerate(itertools.chain([first_line, ], fhd)):
>     File "C:\Users\Vaibhav Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
>       return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
>   **UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 2250: character maps to undefined**

Comment: Have you tried this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33001877/3700867

Comment: @cr3 Yep! I have already tried that but it didn't worked!

Comment: Have you tried calling `np.genfromtxt` with `encoding='utf-8'`?

Comment: @cr3 Now it prints something "nan"

Comment: Now try calling `np.genfromtxt` with `dtype=None` and keep the encoding argument.

Comment: @cr3 Now it just prints the location of dataset file "Datasets/CompleteDataset.csv"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Cr3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3700867/cr3) for helping me through comments. At last this code worked for me:

> import numpy as np
>   fifa = np.genfromtxt('Datasets/CompleteDataset.csv', delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8', dtype=str)
>   np_fifa = np.array(fifa)
>   print(np_fifa)

Output :

> [['' 'Name' 'Age' ... 'RW' 'RWB' 'ST']
> ['0' 'Cristiano Ronaldo' '32'
>   ... '91.0' '66.0' '92.0']
> ['1' 'L. Messi' '30' ... '91.0' '62.0'
>   '88.0']
> ['17978' 'J. Young' '17' ... '44.0' '32.0' '45.0']
>   ['17979' 'J. Lundstram' '18' ... '44.0' '46.0' '41.0']
> ['17980' 'L.
>   Sackey' '18' ... '29.0' '38.0' '31.0']]